# Open another Excel workbook and attain a column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to create a UserForm with VBA where it would silently open a Workbook (with a CommandButton) and copy the contents of specified column to a ListBox in the same GUI, but upon running, it opens the sheet and sticks there without data copyback. Here is the bulk part of the code. Can anyone please help?

```
Sub OpenBox()

Dim owbSource As Workbook
Dim rSource As Range

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Show
    fullPath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set owbSource = Workbooks.Open(fullPath, True, True)

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Set rSource = owbSource.Worksheets("Property").Range("B5:B77")

ListBox1.RowSource = rSource

End Sub
```

Comment: `ListBox1.RowSource = rSource` -> `ListBox1.RowSource = rSource.Address`

Comment: Thanks. I modified the command, but still get Run-Time error '424' Object required. Debug points to the modified line.

Comment: Then you should add more code details as to: where/how is the userform instantiated and who/how's calling `OpenBox()`

Comment: This was all the code I have, not sure how to instantiate the UserForm. OpenBox is the CommandButton name. The UserForm is run from VB.  I just modified the first line to   Private Sub OpenBox_Click()

Answer (score 0):

I have change some lines, please try this

```
Dim owbSource As Workbook
Dim rSource As Range
Dim rsheetsource As Worksheet
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Show
    fullPath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set owbSource = Workbooks.Open(fullPath, True, True)
Set rsheetsource = owbSource.Sheets("Property")
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Set rSource = rsheetsource.Range("B5:B77")
ListBox1.RowSource = "'" & owbSource.Path & "/[" & owbSource.Name & "]" & rsheetsource.Name & "'!" & rSource.Address
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: HeeLee and @BigBen : Thanks for your comments. I got the listbox filled out by using  ``` ListBox1.List = rSource.Cells.Value ```